# "UNPROTECTED" on the panel

Tags: panel

I recently installed "Bionic Beaver".

On the panel I have a big `UNPROTECTED` string:

[image]]

What should I do about it?

Comment: We would need to know what's providing that notice.  It sounds like there's more than just Bionic on this system.  What happens when you click "UNPROTECTED"?  Does anything load up?

Comment: Clicking unprotected does nothing. I also looked through various logs searching for unprotected and didn't find anything. I also have Windows 10 on the machine.

Comment: After you completed the installation of Ubuntu 18.04, exactly what else did you install?

Comment: Great question! I had NordVPN Status running which was putting the notice on the panel. After removing it the "notice" went away. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JohnDarms Please post that as answer below by clicking the "answer your own question" button to help future readers. It's absolutely fine to answer your own question.

Answer (score 2):

> I had NordVPN Status running which was putting the notice on the panel.
>   After removing it the "notice" went away.

Source: [a comment by OP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077254/unprotected-on-the-panel#comment1769186_1077254)